# Forwarding signal to remote child from local parent over ssh

Tags: ssh, signals

I have a script which executes remote command and redirect output to local file.

Remote command just reads list of pcap files continuously and writes to stdout.

The final command is like this -

```
ssh root@host /sbin/path-to-utility | cat > local-file
```

The script which executes this remote command needs to have signal handler to save the state of overall transfer.

Also I want to send signal to remote command or process to stop reading pcap files, so that exit after finishing writing current file.

**I tried -t option and signal handling works perfectly fine, but it adds some extra characters to the actual output written by remote command and disturbs my pcap data.**

Either I need to handle signal without -t option over ssh or I need to find out why ssh -t is adding additional bytes to actual data.

Please help!

Thanks,

Sachin.

Answer (score 0):

The `-t` option tells ssh to allocate a terminal. The extra characters are intended to be interpreted by your terminal.

Perhaps then you should tell ssh you are using a different terminal, one that will not generate any extra characters, but will still pass on signals. Does this work?

```
TERM=dumb ssh root@host /sbin/path-to-utility | cat > local-file
```

(I don't know what would be the best value to use for TERM.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I tried you solution without no luck!

Also I used different TERM values like "linux", still not working!

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Perhaps `TERM=''` (two single quotes)?